# Converting string to decimal according to culture and thoughts

Tags: c#, string, decimal, globalization, cultureinfo

All these following methods accept comma in the string to work correctly and convert string to decimal.

```
decimal.Parse("12,3", CurrentCulture) //or InvariantCulture it doesn't matter.
decimal.TryParse("12,3", out d)
Convert.ToDecimal("12,3")
```

I thnik the reason is the server code (C#) executes based on the current culture. And it is because I have added `<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />` to the web.config file. And CurrencyDecimalSeparator for current culture is comma.

Now my questions are if I move the code (release) to a server that is located in the another region and country which has another CurrencyDecimalSeparator, does it throw an exception? how this string converting to decimal related to the culture works? Is there a general way to handle it?

Comment: If you wanted to know if it throws an exception you could simply change the culture of your machine and try it.

Comment: Are these strings only being assembled inside code you control or do you have to deal with parsing external data?

Comment: no not assembled inside the code, people insert them from different countries